# Managing core objects in iOS

Tags: android, ios, singleton

I've been tasked with porting an Android app over the iOS.  Unfortunately, I've never written an iOS app before so I have some fundamental questions.

In Android, the app we wrote maintained a few different core objects that we used frequently in a class that extended android.app.Application.  When we needed to access these objects, we would call [getApplication();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29)  In this class, we stored two Dictionaries of custom objects, an ArrayList, and a few booleans, ints, and strings.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this in iOS?  I looked into a singleton class that would hold all the dictionaries, arraylists, and other data, but I read that this singleton will exist in memory the entire time that the app is running.  In Android, the Application class would sometimes be garbage collected after some time of inactivity, so we had to reload it.  If, in iOS, this singleton class lives in memory for the entire lifetime of the app, should I be worried about using too much memory?  Should I serialize these objects and store them on disk, recreating them when needed?

Comment: Just a correction, Android does not GC the application.  You might be confusing it with your application process being destroyed by Android when your app is in the background and more memory is needed but this is not GC.  Therefore, your entire application class "lives in memory for the entire lifetime of the app" and thus, can see no difference between your Android approach and the iOS singleton.

Comment: @Simon yes I must be confusing it with the application process being destroyed by Android.  Will something similar happen in iOS?  My fear  was the user is using my (iOS) app, hits the (home?) button on their iOS device, and my data is still sitting in memory unnecessarily.  Will iOS handle this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do iOS.  I'm sure someone here can answer that for you.  However, I'd be stunned is iOS would leak a singleton if the app was killed in the background. What I do know is that iOS multitasking is not as sophisticated as Android and if the user presses home, your app is asked to quit.

Comment: @Simon your application isn't asked to quit if you press home; that was true in the past but ceased to be so on relevant devices when Apple integrated its version of multitasking. What you do lose is all your processing time unless you fit within certain strictly-defined categories of app, and even then you respond in a time limited event-driven manner rather than being able to process as much as you want.

Comment: Ah, didn't know what.  Thanks for the update Tommy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android.app.Application` sounds similar to iOS's App Delegate (`UIApplicationDelegate`). Certain methods in the App Delegate get called when the application's state changes, check out the following methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

The first one will be called when the application isn't in the background and is about to be closed (see Tommy's comment), and the latter if it's going into the background. I'd suggest serializing the data to permanent storage every time the app enters the background if there's been changes.

Later on, you can get a reference to your custom App Delegate by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and casting the result to your custom subclass. I'd also suggest not storing the data directly in the App Delegate, but in a model object that the delegate has a reference to (it should help keep things a bit cleaner and give you a bit more flexibility).

Comment: You won't get `willTerminate:` if you're terminated while in the background, so serialising upon going into the background is definitely the way to do it. But there's no need to free memory and all that — rebuild and deserialise only upon `applicationDidLaunch:`, otherwise treat your in-memory storage as write-through cache.

Comment: Good point! I wasn't aware of that corner case, could definitely bite some people if they assumed it was always safe.

Comment: @Kitsune I see the similarities.  I think I read somewhere that using the App Delegate for this purpose is bad practice, though.  Anyways, let me get this straight.  I should serialize and store the data in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and deserialize and instantiate in `applicationDidLaunch`?  Otherwise just access my data through the App Delegate?

Comment: @kdg123 I've never seen it suggested that would be a bad practice (storing the data directly in App Delegate itself, though, might be). And yes, you'd use `applicationDidEnterBackground` for saving, and `applicationDidLaunch` for loading.